# MY SQL ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, create-table

> Executing SQL script in server
>   ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>     INDEX `fk_film_actor_actor_id_idx` (`actor_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
>     CONSTRAINT `fk' at line 10

SQL Code:

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `baza_filmova`.`film_actor`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `baza_filmova`.`film_actor` (
      `film_actor_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `film_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `actor_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `role` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`film_actor_id`),
      INDEX `fk_film_actor_film_id_idx` (`film_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      INDEX `fk_film_actor_actor_id_idx` (`actor_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_film_actor_film_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`)
        REFERENCES `baza_filmova`.`film` (`film_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_film_actor_actor_id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`)
        REFERENCES `baza_filmova`.`actor` (`actor_id`)
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
        ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>
> Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>   Nothing to fetch

I am using MySQL Workbench 8.0.18. I start making model and when I click to forward engineer it makes only to tables bud doesn't make this film_actor. Its middle table between film table and actor table.

Do somebody have same error before and how can I fix it.

PS: I doesn't make syntax error, I check my tables and foreign keys multiple times.

Comment: What is version of MySQL are you running?  `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: Look does `VISIBLE` is allowed for your version...

Comment: YOU use MariaDB. It doesn't even know that the word "VISIBLE" exists when applied to [CREATE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/).

Comment: Click "Affects me" on https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269

Answer (score 4):

The error message really make it looks like the `VISIBLE` keyword is not supported in your version of MySQL/Maria DB.

This feature was introduced in MySQL 8.0. In MariaDB, it is not available as of now.

Note that `VISIBLE` is the default setting when not specified, so you don't actually need it in your query: the following is equivalent (and should work):

```
  INDEX `fk_film_actor_film_id_idx` (`film_id`),
  INDEX `fk_film_actor_actor_id_idx` (`actor_id`),
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to 10.3.3?  This implies that it has not been implemented yet:  https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7317

Comment: @RickJames: you are correct, I confused this with invisible *columns*... answer updated.